# JTable add rows according to length of array

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

After getting data from my database, I have to show this in a `JTable`.
In my design I can specify how much rows the `JTable` should have.

But when my array of data is longer then the specified rows, I get an exception.
This is because my table is too small for all the data I want to add in it.

How can I dynamically add rows to my table according to the size of the array?

```
TableModel tmPerson = taTablePerson.getModel();

    for (int index = 0; index < arrpBag.length; index++)
    {
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getId(), index, 0);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getRijksregisternummer(), index, 1);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getNaam(), index, 2);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getVoornaam(), index, 3);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getStraat(), index, 4);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getNummer(), index, 5);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getBus(), index, 6);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getPostnummer(), index, 7);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getGemeente(), index, 8);
        dtmPerson.setValueAt(arrpBag[index].getTelefoonnummer(), index, 9);
    } 

    //Create extra rows when not enough
    if (taTabelPersonen.getRowCount() < arrpBag.length) 
    {
    //What code should be placed here?
    }

    taTabelPersonen.setModel(dtmPersoon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I dynamically add rows to my table according to the size of
>   the array?

You can use a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) as table model and call [addRow(Object[] rowData)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) method to dinamically add rows and automatically increasing the row's count. This way you can forget about a fixed row's count. For instance you may have something like this:

```
Object[] header = new Object[]{"Id", "Rijksregisternummer", "Naam", "Voornaam"
                              ,"Straat", "Nummer", "Bus", "Postnummer"
                              ,"Gemeente", "Telefoonnummer"};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(header, 0);

for (int index = 0; index < arrpBag.length; index++) {
    Object[] row = new Object[]{ arrpBag[index].getId()
                               , arrpBag[index].getRijksregisternummer()
                               , arrpBag[index].getNaam()
                               , arrpBag[index].getVoornaam()
                               , arrpBag[index].getStraat()
                               , arrpBag[index].getNummer()
                               , arrpBag[index].getBus()
                               , arrpBag[index].getPostnummer()
                               , arrpBag[index].getGemeente()
                               , arrpBag[index].getTelefoonnummer() };

    model.addRow(row);
}

taTabelPersonen.setModel(model);
```